Probability of Poisson process with delay producing given sequence
Suppose we have a Poisson process that outputs events of type $A$ (with an average of $1$ every unit time). We know that for every event of type $A$, an event of type $B$ happens after exactly $T$ time (here $T$ is some positive parameter). How can I find the probability of a given sequence occurring? Here, I am only considering those sequences where the number of $B$ events matches the number of $A$ events. We also don't really need to worry about the sequences where the number of $B$ events matches the number of $A$ events earlier on in the sequence, since we can split it up into two or more pieces, and multiply the corresponding probabilities together (e.g. $P(ABAB)=P(AB)P(AB)$).
For example, the probability of the sequence $AB$ is the probability that the next event of type $A$ happens after $T$ time, so is given by $\exp(-T)$. As another example, the probability of the sequence $AABB$ is given by $P(t_1<T)\cdot P(t_2>T)=(1-\exp(-T))\exp(-T)$, where the $t_i$ are drawn from an exponential distribution (for the waiting times between blocks). The sequence $AABABB$ has probability $P(t_1,t_2<T<t_1+t_2,t_3)=P(t_3>T)\cdot P(t_1,t_2<T<t_1+t_2)$, which is given by $$\exp(-T)\int_0^T\int_{T-t_1}^T\exp(-(t_1+t_2))dt_2dt_1=e^{-T}\left(Te^{-T}-e^{-T}+e^{-2T}\right).$$
As I did in the last example, I know we can set up an integral to find the probability for a given sequence. The Erlang distribution was helpful for certain sequences, but for most sequences, working through the integration was unwieldy. Is there some simple way to calculate the probability of a given sequence?
This comes up when calculating transition probabilities in a blockchain mining game, with fixed latency. The events of type $A$ are the "mining" actions, while the events of type $B$ are the "broadcast" actions.

For a more general example, we can use the Erlang distribution to show that the probability of the sequence $A^nB^n$ is given by $\left(1-e^{-T}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k!}T^k\right)e^{-T}$.
